# Socket.IO client library gives "welcome to socket.io" message

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

After some time I tried working with node.js and socket.IO again, but it didn't work as expected:

### My setup

1. Downloaded node.js from github and compiled it on my **external webserver** running on debian squeeze
2. Created a directory for the node.js project
3. Added socket.io locally with npm
4. Created socketIO_server.js and just added this single line of code:

   ```
   var socketIO = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
   ```
5. Started the socketIO_server.js and console log says "info - socket.io started"
6. Opening http://domain.tld:8000 gives the message "welcome to socket.io"

### The Problem

When I try to access the client library by http://domain.tld:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js it gives also the message "welcome to socket.io", but the console log shows "served static content /socket.io.js". I have no idea why this happens!
I though the nginx server running parallel causes this problem but stopping the server didn't change anything.

Thanks for reading and help!

Comment: What version of socket.io and nodejs are you running? (Assuming the latest) right now.

Comment: socket.io 0.9.9, nodejs 0.9.1-pre

Comment: I did some digging and didn't find anything the stood out. I've linked to the relative part of the socket.io code. I don't have 0.9.1-pre installed but you could open up your node_modules directory and do some digging around the socket.io code. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L571

Comment: Ok, what I did meanwhile: I installed node.js/socket.io also on my virtual machine and exactly ran into same problem when serving the client lib. Seems like a bug. Question: How do I apply changes on modifications on node_modules? "npm rebuild socket.io"? Just changed the "welcome to socket.io" message, but it still shows up the original one.

Comment: Any edits you make in the node_modules should be applied. Nodejs will look inside of node_modules for anything that is request via `require`. Did you restart the node process after applying the changes? EDIT: Found something interesting after grepping through all the files. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.io.js#L58

Comment: Looks like your problem may have to do with this line which removes the initial `.on('request')` handler. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L115

Comment: You are a genius! Seems like the default event listener from lib/socket.io.js should be removed, but isn't. So I just called server.removeAllListeners after they are stored in "oldListeners". No it works as expected.. Did they changed the nodejs Server-Object or why this stopped working?

Comment: I'm not sure. I will have to download 0.9.1-pre and run a few tests. It could be a bug with that was introduced after they did the last 0.8.x stable release. This looks to stem from the EventEmitter lib.

Comment: Looks like this commit is to blame: https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/20e12e4be37f394672c001fdb9b05c0275731901#L1R245
They changed it to return a copy of the listeners instead of the actually array. So when socket.io calls `this.oldListeners = server.listeners('request').splice(0);` its not actually removing the listener.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by a commit made to the EventEmitter lib of nodejs in a recent change. I've opened an issue on socket.io.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/987

**UPDATE**

This issue has been fixed as of socket.io 0.9.12

Fix:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.12/lib/manager.js#L116

Commit:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/commit/0d3313f536d0231932dd6617db449a071f5bc03a

---

**Can not serve socket.io.js when listening on port. (node 0.9.1-pre, socket.io 0.9.9)**

Due to a recent commit to node, you can no longer splice out event listeners. This causes socket.io to display the welcome message when trying to access the socket.io.js client file as the original event listener does not get removed.

Example breakage:

```
var socketIO = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
```

This breaks due to the way node 0.9.1-pre changed the way you can access listeners for the EventEmitter lib.

nodejs commit that breaks socket.io

> Make EventEmitter.listeners(event) return a copy of the listeners array instead
>   of the array itself.

```
EventEmitter.prototype.listeners = function(type) {
   if (!isArray(this._events[type])) {
     this._events[type] = [this._events[type]];
   }        
-  return this._events[type];   
+  return this._events[type].slice(0);
};
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/20e12e4be37f394672c001fdb9b05c0275731901#L1R245

Relative socket.io code:

```
// reset listeners
this.oldListeners = server.listeners('request').splice(0);
```

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L115

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few days ago. Had to downgrade socket.io to v0.8.7 and it worked fine.