# SocketIO can not serve static content after I upgraded nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I upgraded my nodejs from 0.6 to 0.10

before socketIO works fine, but now whenever client request "socket.io.js"

```
"http://localhost:49991/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

The response is only one line.

```
Welcome to socket.io.
```

Not the actual file "socket.io.js". My app crash because of this.

The output of sever console seems to be fine:

```
 debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

My socket.io version is 0.9.*. What could possibly be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

found this is duplicated:
[Socket.IO client library gives "welcome to socket.io" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889132/socket-io-client-library-gives-welcome-to-socket-io-message)