# Troubleshooting socket.io error message

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I inherited a project which utilizes `node.js` and `socket.io`, both of which I am not too familiar with.

I installed `node.js` and `npm` via homebrew and `socket.io` via npm.

The current setup has two different "sites": The frontend, that the user interacts with, and the backend that handles all the communications with a DB. The application uses several different displays, and the previous developer deemed it best to use the current setup.

I can successfully start the node server by invoking `node node-server.js`. In the head of the `node-server.js`, `socket.io` is being called like:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8090);
[...]
```

In my front end, I call `socket.io` like this:

```
<script src="http://192.168.1.111:8090/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.111:8090');
 [...]
```

However, when I debug the page, I get the following error messages:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'to' (anonymous function)     socket.io.js:1
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io    sample.html
```

In the terminal window, where I started the node server, I get the output:

debug - served static content /socket.io.js

I should add that the two sites reside in separate folders - I access the frontend through a local Apache server, the piece that interacts with the DB sits someplace else on the same machine.

How would I correctly call the socket.io in my client?
Is there a way to enable better debugging?

### Update

So the `to` in the error message, is because whenever the browser tries to load the `socket.js` file, it gets the reply of `Welcome to socket.io`

Comment: Does this load? http://192.168.1.111:8090/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: When I visit this URL, I receive a "Welcome to socket.io" message. It does not load the JS file.

Comment: Try to get that working then. http://socket.io/docs/server-api

Comment: Should the actual JS file load at that URL?

Comment: Apparently the connection issue is caused by a bug in some `socket.io` version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889132/socket-io-client-library-gives-welcome-to-socket-io-message). `npm` intially installed 0.9.10, but when I instead installed 0.9.16, that appears to be working. No onto debugging the app itself. Thanks for your input, @laggingreflex.